# Verificação de input com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estou fazendo um formulario com envio de 2 tipos de foto, e gostaria de saber como faço pra fazer uma verificação do javascript pra ver se a pessoa enviou alguma das 2 opções, e se não enviou nenhuma das 2 não prossegue para proxima pagina...

```html
 <div class="fileUpload btn">
 <div>

  <span style="width:250px">
  <img src="images/enviar1.png" width="235" height=""/></span></div>
       
     <input type="file" name="img1"  id="img1" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" />
                </div>
                 <div class="fileUpload btn" >
         <div>
          <span style="width:250px">
         <img src="images/enviar2.png" width="235" height=""/></span></div>

     <input type="file" name="img2"  id="img2" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" />

    
</div>

<input style="margin-left:25px;" type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="CONTINUAR"/>
```

Comment: Usa jquery no projeto?

Comment: jquery-2.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível usar a função `submit` do nosso amigo jquery, ao realizar o envio do formulário 
, é feito uma verificação na chamada da função.

O que foi feito no código a baixo, foi verificar se foi selecionado pelo menos uma imagem em um dos dois inputs, se existir ele continua e envia o formulário, caso contrário encerra a aplicação e mostra um alerta.

```js
// Executa ao enviar o formulário, <form>
$('form').submit(function(){
// Verifica se não foi selecionado nada nos dois inputs
if($('#img1').val() === "" && $('#img2').val() === ""){
  alert('selecione uma imagem');
return false
}

alert('enviado');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="fileUpload btn">
 <div>
    <span style="width:250px">
  <img src="images/enviar1.png" width="235" height=""/></span>     </div>
  <input type="file" name="img1"  id="img1" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" />
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn" >
  <div>
    <span style="width:250px">
    <img src="images/enviar2.png" width="235" height=""/></span>
  </div>
  <input type="file" name="img2"  id="img2" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" />
</div>
<input style="margin-left:25px;" type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="CONTINUAR"/>
</form>
```

---

Referência: [Submit - Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Ele está passando direto pro alerta Enviado e indo pra proxima pagina !

Comment: Alterei o código para interromper a operação caso for enviado.

Comment: Não tipo, só quero que interrompa se a pessoa não fizer o upload, se fizer, carrega e vai pra proxima pagina entendeu?

Comment: Sim, mas é isso que o código faz, ele é interrompido somete se o não existir nada selecionado nos inputs.

Comment: Não está funcionando não, aqui no teste do propio site ele aparece os 2 alertas se vc nao enviar nada..

Comment: Removi o `return false` do lugar errado, pronto!

Comment: Cara funcionou, muito obrigado ! se eu for fazer só um eu removo  && $('#img2').val() === "") ??

Comment: Isso, nesse caso ele verifica se os dois elementos estão vazios, caso queria verificar apenas um seria dessa forma mesmo, `if($('#img1').val() === "")`

Comment: Muito obrigado, valeu demais mesmo !

Answer (score 0):

utilize o plugin [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

ela é uma biblioteca complete de validação para formulários, muito boa e simples de ser instalada e de utilizar.

```
$(seletorDoFormulario).valid()
```

este exemplo acima lhe retornará um booleano assim facilitando a vida para saber se o formulario é valido para ser enviado.

Answer (score -1):

No seu caso, como você só precisa saber se ele enviou ao menos uma das duas, o atributo *required* do HTML no primeiro input não seria suficiente?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="fileUpload btn">
    <div>
    <span style="width:250px">
        <img src="images/enviar1.png" width="235" height=""/></span>     </div>
  <input type="file" name="img1"  id="img1" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" required />
</div>
<div class="fileUpload btn" >
  <div>
    <span style="width:250px">
    <img src="images/enviar2.png" width="235" height=""/></span>
  </div>
  <input type="file" name="img2"  id="img2" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="" class="upload" />
</div>
<input style="margin-left:25px;" type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="CONTINUAR"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `required` vai obriga-lo a sempre marcar a opção 1, sendo que segundo o autor ele pode escolher marcar 1 **ou** 2, desde que marque pelo menos alguma opção e não sempre a primeira